# IConfiguration.GetSection.Bind returning null when array is present in json environment variables

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm working with Azure Functions and am having trouble reading in some environment variables (in the form of a json file for local testing). My local.settings.json file that contains some values

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "TokenValidationSettings:Audience": "AnAudience",
    "TokenValidationSettings:Secret": "ASecret",
    "TokenValidationSettings:ValidIssuers": [ "Issuer1", "Issuer2],
  }
}
```

I have a C# object that I want to bind that section to, so that I can inject the settings following the IOptions pattern. I've done this before **without** an array and it hasn't been a problem, but all the values are null when I include the ValidIssuers array in json file.

```
public class TokenValidationSettings
{
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string[] ValidIssuers { get; set; }
}
```

In Program.cs I set up the host and services.

```
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => services
            .AddLogging()
            .InjectConfigSectionsAsIOptions())
        .Build();
```

InjectConfigSectionsAsIOptions looks like this.

```
public static IServiceCollection InjectConfigSectionsAsIOptions(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions<TokenValidationSettings>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) => {
        configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenValidationSettings)).Bind(settings);
    });

    return services;
}
```

Am I going to have to do things a bit more manually here instead of being able to just use GetSection > Bind, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your json is not formatted correctly. Change this line

**"TokenValidationSettings:ValidIssuers": [ "Issuer1", "Issuer2],**

to this

**"TokenValidationSettings:ValidIssuers": [ "Issuer1", "Issuer2"]**

Secondly you need to scope down to the section from the top level node.
Change this line

**configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenValidationSettings)).Bind(settings);**

to this line

**configuration.GetSection($"Values:{nameof(TokenValidationSettings)}").Bind(settings);**

Lastly, and this part depends on where the json file lives, but if it's a separate json file in your application you need to register it. Here is a simple example.

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json").Build());
            });
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Ah, I think the JSON formatting was just incorrect in my question - sorry about that. It's as it should be in the project. For the scoping down part, I believe this is done implicitly in Azure Funcions as it works without "Values:" (as long as I leave the array part out). I also should have specified that I'm using isolated process so all that configuration registration is taken care of (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide).